# Why does Data service not return values to application, but returns it to browser? How to fix it?

Tags: c#, web-services, odata

Just have a simple OData web-service:

```
public class TestService : DataService<ASUTBEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead
             | EntitySetRights.WriteMerge
             | EntitySetRights.WriteReplace);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }

    [WebGet]
    public List<Search_Result1> FindCarOwner(string searchString)
    {
        List<Search_Result1> result = new List<Search_Result1>();
        result.AddRange(CurrentDataSource.FindContragents(searchString).ToList());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Search_Result1 - is a complex type, auto-generated from stored procedure of Sql Server in EDMX file.
If i type in browser something like this: hxxp://MyWebService/Test.svc/FindCarOwner?searchString='SomeString' . It returns something like this:

```
<FindCarOwner xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
    <element xmlns:p2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" p2:type="ASUTBModel.Search_Result1">
        <Name>
        Name of the company
        </Name>
        <ID p2:type="Edm.Int32">538175</ID>
    </element>
    ... and 3 elements more (total 4 elements)
</FindCarOwner>
```

But if i try to call this function from application, it returns List with Capacity=4 and Count=0. I do it like this:

```
ASUTBOData.ASUTBEntities context = new ASUTBOData.ASUTBEntities(new Uri(servicePath));
context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
context.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
List<Search_Result1> preresult;
try
{
    preresult = context.Execute<Search_Result1>(new Uri("hxxp://MyWebService/Test.svc/FindCarOwner?searchString='SomeString'")).ToList();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return null;
}
```

Why does application cannot convert received values? Is it fixable, or i must to find other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Service client doesn't support nothing but EntityType materialisation from Schema, described in OData (for me it is MyWebService/Test.svc/$metadata).
The only solution i could find is to use WebClient from System.Net

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(wc.DownloadString(new Uri(request)));
var res = xdoc.Root.Descendants( ((XNamespace)@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices") + 
                                            "element");

preresult = res.Select(xe => xe.Value).ToList();
```